# React/CSS : How to move button to the left so it matches beginning of search bar

Tags: css, reactjs

I wish to align the button to where the search bar starts: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc6Bt.png). How can I make them start together?

However, even after adding a style to the button it stays in the same place:

```
  render() {
    const { suggestions, value, filteredProjects, isANDOn, text } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: "Search",
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <PageWrapper headerBar={true} search={true} sideMenu={true}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <h1 className="mt0 mb1">Archive</h1>
            <button
              style={{ float: "left" }} //the button
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              label={"Click to toggle!"}
            >
              {text}
            </button>
        <Autosuggest
          suggestions={suggestions}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
          getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
          renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
          inputProps={inputProps}
        />
```

Comment: can u show us your search bar too ? ill try make you an example.

Comment: I've added it to my code, but its from a personal UI so I don't think you will be able to use it in an example...

Answer (score 1):

not need to use `float`, just Wrap your button and input inside a div with `display:"flex"`, should solve problem.

```js
const App = () => (
      <div>
        <div style={styles.parent}>
          <h1 className="mt0 mb1">Archive</h1>
          <div style={styles.searchSection}>
            <button>
              AND
            </button>
            <input type="text"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );

const styles = {
  parent: {
      width: "100%",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection:"column",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
  },
  searchSection: {
      display: "flex"
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Hi appreciate the answer. However I meant that that it should start where the search bar is, as in on top of the search bar but from the same position.

Comment: U mean `position:absolute` for button on top of search bar ?